# Login failed for new user SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a user that only has access to a few views and procedures. The user seems to be created fine, but when I attempt to log in to the user account using the connection string below, I get the error `Login failed for user 'Interface_Admin'`.

```
User ID=Interface_Admin;Password=letmein01;Integrated Security=False;server=SQL02;database=TESTDB;Trusted_Connection=False;
```

My code to create the user and grant permissions is below.

```
USE TESTDB
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'Interface_Admin') DROP USER Interface_Admin
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.syslogins WHERE name = 'Interface_Admin_Login') DROP LOGIN Interface_Admin_Login
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'Interface_Users') DROP ROLE Interface_Users

-- Create role and add user accounts
CREATE ROLE Interface_Users
CREATE LOGIN Interface_Admin_Login WITH PASSWORD = 'letmein01'
CREATE USER Interface_Admin FROM LOGIN Interface_Admin_Login
EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename='Interface_Users', @membername='Interface_Admin'
GO

-- Grant permissions
-- Views
GRANT SELECT ON Vw_Interface_Main TO Interface_Users;

-- Procedures
GRANT EXECUTE ON Proc_GetNextFileSequence TO Interface_Users;
GRANT EXECUTE ON Proc_OutboundFiles TO Interface_Users;
GRANT EXECUTE ON Proc_InsertOrUpdateFile TO Interface_Users;
```

Comment: Mixed authentication turned on?

Comment: @dfundako not entirely sure what you mean there. I take it that's a setting in SQL Server somewhere?

Comment: Run this: SELECT CASE SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly')   
WHEN 1 THEN 'Windows Authentication'   
WHEN 0 THEN 'Windows and SQL Server Authentication'   
END as [Authentication Mode]

Comment: In SSMS, right-click the SQL Server node at the top, select properties, then click on the "Security" tab, and ensure SQL Server authentication mode allows both Windows and SQL Server logins.

Comment: Yes the server allows both Windows and SQL Server logins

Comment: Go to the instance > security folder> logins > right click the login and click properties. Go to the Status tab and confirm the login has access granted to connect to the db engine and the login is enabled.

Comment: @dfundako yes, it is enabled and permission to connect to database engine is set to "Grant"

Comment: And you can confirm when you go to SSMS and look at the TestDB after running your scripts that the user 'Interface_Admin' is there? Are you making it on the right db?

Comment: @JacobH yes they are different... it might be my misunderstanding but I was under the impression that the correct process was to create a login and then create a user for that login. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @dfundako Yes the user is present in TESTDB > Security > Users. The role is also present in TESTDB > Security > Roles.

Comment: Can you find the login failed message in the SQL error log? It should give you a state number, which will help determine the problem. It'll be something like `Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: n.` - need the value of n.

Comment: @GarethLyons 
"2018-03-16 16:46:39.17 Logon       Login failed for user 'Interface_Admin'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided." Am I supposed to be logging in with the *USER* name or the *LOGIN* name??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original script has Create Login with `Interface_Admin_Login`, but then User Id in the connection string is `Interface_Admin`.

Logins should be done with the Login name, not user name. Login = access to the instance, users are used to handle permissions within each database. Generally users are created with the same name as the login to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think this is down to a misunderstanding on my part, but I was able to resolve this by giving the same name to both the user and the login.

```
-- Create role and add user accounts
CREATE ROLE Interface_Users
CREATE LOGIN Interface_Admin WITH PASSWORD = 'letmein01'
CREATE USER Interface_Admin FROM LOGIN Interface_Admin
EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename='Interface_Users', @membername='Interface_Admin'
GO
```

Comment: Yep, you need to login using the login name. Login = access to the instance, then users are used to handle permissions within each database. Generally you'll create users with the same name as the login to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ok, thanks for elaborating, that explains a lot. If you phrase that as an answer then I'll mark it as best answer.